# What is the correct way to check for the existence of a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am having problems with an older database creation script. I am wondering if it has anything to do with the way it is determining existence of certain objects.

For tables the line is

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[tablename]' AND type in (N'U'))
BEGIN
Create table...
END
```

This seems wrong, after looking at sys.objects, I don't think it would ever have it there. Is this a bug? If so what would be a better way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') IS NULL 

  CREATE Table dbo.TableName 
  ....... 


GO
```

OR you could do something like....

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP TABLE dbo.TableName 
GO

  CREATE Table dbo.TableName 
  .......     
GO
```

The `OBJECT_ID()` function also takes a second (optional) parameters, it is the Object type, for user defined tables you would use `U`, something like....

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName' , 'U') IS NULL 

  CREATE Table dbo.TableName 
  ....... 


GO
```

Comment: Is the way this script doing it valid?

Comment: The query in your question will also work, but you have a missing parenthesis for the `object_id` function, other than this it should work fine but it is a bit lengthy query to write, my suggested method has less code and much cleaner :)

Comment: M. Ali's is the most commonly used form. IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName' , 'U') IS NULL